# npm ERR! Invalid package name - When deploying Nuxt3 project in firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, firebase-hosting, notion-api

Deploying my Nuxt3 project has been succeed in firebase hosting, though, after I installed `@notionhq/client` for using Notion API, and then $ firebase deploy, this error occured.

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function server(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@notionhq/client/build" of package "@notionhq/client/build@2.2.2": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

I've been struggling with it for 2days..
Hope someone tell the way to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy succeed after removing "@notionhq/client/build" from package.json in .output/server ... I found that "@notionhq/client/build" does not exist in `https://www.npmjs.com/` by searching. I really don't know why @notionhq/client/build appeared after build.